# MongoDB Replica establishment running on two different kubernetes cluster on different physical host

Tags: mongodb, networking, kubernetes, replication

Objective : MongoDB Replica establishment running on two different kubernetes cluster on different physical host.

**Host 1** : kubernetes cluster -1 : A pod is running with let say (mongo1 instance with replication set name “my-mongo-set”). Service is created with pod running behind let say mongo1-service.

**Host 2** : Kubernetes cluster-2 : Another pod is running with (mong2 instance with same replication set name “my-mongo-set”). Service is created with pod running behind let say mongo2-service.

now, i am unable to set the mongoDb in replication mode from inside the pod to another pod.

**Host 1**: Kubernetes-Cluster-1                        **Host 2** : Kubernetes-Cluster-2

Mongo1-service                                  Mongo2-service
Mongo1-pod                                      Mongo2-pod

I need pod to pod communication between two different kubernetes cluster node running onto different machines.

I am unable to expose the Kubernetes mongo-service IP using either type as NodePort, LoadBalancer, ingress controller(kong) etc.

I am new to kubernetes and I have installed the kubernetes (kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet) through apt-get and then run the Kubeadm init command.

Any suggestions how to achieve this …. ?

Comment: Use `hostNetwork` then.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you unable to expose mongo-service IP?

Comment: Please write the log when you have problems, so that readers could understand and help.